# React Native APK build failure Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete'

Tags: react-native

Suddenly i cannot build a release apk with the following error:

> [04/07/2017, 20:37:22]    Transforming files (18437ms) bundle:
>   start bundle: finish bundle: Writing bundle output to:
>   D:\likecounter\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
>   bundle: Done writing bundle output bundle: Copying 13 asset files
>   bundle: Done copying assets
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete '
>   (ProgressCompleteEvent)
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I tried to use the suggested flags, but they weren't helpful.

The only thing i can think that could cause this problem is when i tried to press the run button on Android Studio it suggested to allow something that has to do with "instant run" and i naively agreed.

I tried to take the following steps:

- Change gradle version from 2.2.3 to 2.1.2
- Cancel instant run in Android studio configuration by reaching Build,
  Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> un-select everything

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I solved it by running the command with plain console as follow:

```
YOURCOMMAND --console plain
```

Comment: @Star_Man No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

react-native 0.50.4

./android/build.gradle > buildscript > dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

./android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties > distribution url:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

solved with:

```
gradlew assembleRelease --console plain
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build an a release apk after updating to the last version of Android Studio and Gradle

Answer (score 0):

i did gradlew clean
then i close android studio and open it again
then gradlew assembleRelease
then it works

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

Problem solved after open the CMD as Administrator and run gradlew.bat assembleRelease from the android folder.

Answer (score 0):

I manually upgraded `gradle` from 4.2 to 4.3 and the error is no more. (on Windows 10)

Comment: Do you have any information on how to upgrade a React Native project to use gradle 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

The problem never occurs when using Gradle with the following command:

```
gradlew assembleRelease --console plain
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened to me, it took me a while to realize so Im sharing here since it might help others.

I wanted to upload the app to the Google Play Store, then I increaded the version and version name in the AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.girocheck.GirocheckMobile"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="5.0">
...
```

but it happens that I also needed to increase this values in the build.gradle file:

```
...

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5    //make sure you increase these too
        versionName "5.0"//make sure you increase these too
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

...
```

Once I make both files has the same version, the issue stop.

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue at Windows 10.

I'm not 100% sure, But I think it's something to do with the command tool you are using.

If I use ***CMD***, `gradlew assembleRelease` works fine. 
But the issue came up if I use powershell.

On powershell I had to use : `gradlew assembleRelease --console plain`

`--console plain` disables special color characters in the output and that fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

I had faced same error when I generate release apk.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

And using this command, I could find the reason.

```
gradlew assembleRelease --console plain
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.pro
  >   cess.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.
  >   DexIndexOverflowException: field ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

And I could generate release apk by enabling multidex.

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```